How do I quickly exit a stage?
Is there a way to quickly exit a stage in Shantae: Half-Genie Hero? When I revisit stages to complete an objective or get collectibles, it's annoying to have to re-complete the entire stage.

You can use the Whistle to exit a stage. Sky gives it to you near the start of the game. Open up your inventory, select the whistle, then use it to return to the World Select screen.

Additionally, you can purchase a Warp Dance from the shop that allows you to warp between previously visited areas within a world.
